# How to get data from URL with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Basically, I need to get a data from my URL.

The HTML code looks like this:

```
<h4><a th:text="${h.nombre}" class="card-title" style="color: #1c1f23;text-decoration: none;" th:href="@{/hoteles/{id}(id=${h.getId()})}"></a></h4>
```

Example of the kind of URL I get:

```
localhost:8080/hoteles/3
```

Now, I need to get that number and put it on the controller.

My current controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/hoteles/{item}")
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView resultadoHotel(@PathVariable(value="item") String numerito,
                                                 @RequestParam Integer id) {
    List<Hotel> listaHoteles = hotelService.getAll();
    BuscadorID numero = new BuscadorID(id);
    Hotel definitivo = buscadorService.Comparar(numero,listaHoteles);
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("hotelWeb");
    model.addObject("definitivo", definitivo);
    return model;
}
```

I just don't know if I am doing something wrong. I don't get how the RequestParam works.

Comment: `localhost:8080/hotels/3?id=5` is how your URL should look like. item will be "3" as a String and id 5 as Int.

PathVariables = required parts of the URL. PathParams = optional filters after the ? part and separated by , symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In RequestParam without value, by default, it takes an empty String as per doc.
try this...

```
@RequestMapping("/hoteles/{item}")
    public @ResponseBody ModelAndView resultadoHotel(@PathVariable(value="item") String numerito,
                                                     **@RequestParam(value = "id")** Integer id) {
        List<Hotel> listaHoteles = hotelService.getAll();
        BuscadorID numero = new BuscadorID(id);
        Hotel definitivo = buscadorService.Comparar(numero,listaHoteles);
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("hotelWeb");
        model.addObject("definitivo", definitivo);
        return model;
    }
```